# Complex integral over sphere in polar coordinates

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, polar-coordinates

I have trouble evaluating the integral:

$$\int_{B(0,\frac{3R}{|h|})} \frac{1}{(r e^{2i a}-e^{i a})}dr da$$

In fact I just need to estimate it from above in terms of 
$|h|log (\frac{1}{|h|})$, where $R\geq 1$ and $0 < |h| \leq \frac{1}{2}.$

I don't know how to compute an integral about an area with a pole in $re^{ia}=1,$ applying the residue formula does not seem to work.

I got to the point where I need to know now how exactly and if I can apply the Cauchy principal value to:

$$\int_0^\frac{3R}{|h|} \frac{1}{(r-\frac{1}{2})}dr$$

Can somebody tell me if and how that works here? I have trouble finding literature on CPV for the complex case.

Best regards!

Comment: As a follow-up I need to know now how exactly and if I can apply the Cauchy principal value to:

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Quick notation question: Are $r$ and $\alpha$ polar coordinates, and you want the integral of$$-\frac{i}{2}\int \frac{dz\, d\overline{z}}{z^{2} - z}$$over the ball of radius $3R/|h|$ centered at $0$ in the $z$-plane? (If so, that's not quite what you've written.) In any case, you have a complex integral over a region; to apply the "usual techniques" of contour integration, you'd need first to convert to a contour integral, perhaps using Stokes' theorem.